# Is my AJAX URL safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, security

I writing this question, more from insecurity than from absolute ignorance.

I am writing a WordPress theme for a personal use, and I have made a custom registration form for my site members.

Upon completion of the form, I run several AJAX calls on WordPress to check the availability of several user data.

Among the checks I make, is the username availability.

The process it is very simple, as described below:

1. The user enter's the desired username
2. Then continues to the next form field, and a blur event produced on the username field.
3. In this case, I sending an AJAX call on my server to check the username availability.
4. The server returns a JSON document, with the appropriate information
5. If the username exists, then I display an error message, otherwise nothing happens.

Now, my questions.

The ajax send's an object of data like this:

```
data : {
    action : "check_username_availability",
    s      : "my_nonce_key",
    u      : "kiven_username"
}
```

**First Question**

Can I protect my server from DDoS on my AJAX call ? Is it my script vulnerable by this mean ?

**Second Question**

Can this AJAX url to be used in brute force attack to give in attacker the username list of my members ?

And thus, if my script is vulnerable in these terms, can I protect my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Just so long as your script checks form submit and the referring script is your form's address then your "processing" script should be able to determine whether it is being called correctly or not. WordPress does this on the very first line of all its files - it checks for a predefined value and if it's not found it thinks the script is being called directly and calls "die".

Q2. Are you really worried about your usernames being viewable? If you wrote your script to simply return an "available" or "already in use" then that should suffice. Think about the big players on the web. When you register your email it says yay or nay if you can use the username...

Comment: Thansk a lot for your help :) That was all I liked to hear.